# How can I refractor the display functions?

Tags: prolog

I have these display functions:

```
display_siblings(X,Y):-
     setof(X-Y, (siblings(X,Y), ordered(X-Y)), Sibs),
     write('The siblings of'),
            write(X),  
            write('are'),nl, 
            foreach(member(Pair, Sibs), 
               writeln(Pair)),nl, 
        write('% end'), nl.

display_sisters(X,Y):-
     setof(X-Y, (sisters(X,Y), ordered(X-Y)), Sibs),
     write('The sisters of'),
           write(X),  
           write('are'),nl, 
           foreach(member(Pair, Sibs), 
              writeln(Pair)),nl, 
       write('% end'), nl.
```

As you can see only the second argument of setof is changing.
Could I make one display function of both and if it can how can I do this?

Roelof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be:

```
display_siblings(X, Y):-
     setof(X-Y, (siblings(X, Y), ordered(X-Y)), Sibs),
     write('The siblings of'),
     write_sibs(X, Sibs).

display_sisters(X, Y) :=
     setof(X-Y, (sisters(X, Y), ordered(X-Y)), Sibs),
     write('The sisters of'),
     write_sibs(X, Sibs).

write_sibs(X, Sibs):-
     write(X),  
     write('are'), nl, 
     foreach(member(Pair, Sibs), 
         writeln(Pair)),nl, 
     write('% end'), nl.
```

Another way would be:

```
display_siblings(X, Y) :-
    display('siblings', X, Y).

display_sisters(X, Y) :-
    display('sisters', X, Y).

display(Type, X, Y) :-
    setof(X-Y, (call(Type, X, Y), ordered(X-Y)), Sibs),
    write('The '), write(Type), write(' of'),
    write(X),  
    write('are'),nl, 
    foreach(member(Pair, Sibs), 
        writeln(Pair)),nl, 
    write('% end'), nl.
```

Comment: That could definitly work and then do the same for display all where the text would change to "all the Type pairs are" or something like that. For the situation someone is using sister(X,Y) to display all the sister pairs.

Comment: @user3426797 yes, it gives you some options. :)

Comment: yes, for making one big one I necassary that I can check if the arguments are empty or not. SO i have to check somehow if X and Y are empty or have a value. That's will be over my head now.

Comment: @user3426797 There are built-in predicates `var/1` and `nonvar/1` which will tell you if a variable is instantiated or not.

Comment: oke, So I can do var(X),var(Y) -> write "All of the sister of" ; write "The sister of".

Comment: @user3426797 are you asking a new question? I think I answered your original one. Perhaps you should make a new post giving some context which will make your new question much clearer.